# I want the table cell width to be auto. It should only take up the space of the text in the cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to make the cell size of each row to only take up as much space as the text and don't want to fix the width of each cell.
I have used a table component (React Bootstrap) and have hidden the borders.

My code so far:

```
 <Table responsive bordered>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>AWS Certified Solutions Architect</th>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">EC2</Badge>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">Serverless</Badge>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">CI/CD</Badge>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">VPC</Badge>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Front-End</th>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">React</Badge>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">Jest/Enzyme</Badge>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">HTML</Badge>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">CSS</Badge>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Badge variant="info">Bootstrap</Badge>
                </td>
              </tr>
       </tbody>
  </Table>
```

CSS:

```
table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: none !important;
}
```

**What I have:**
[image: Actual]

**Expected:**
[image: Expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: none !important;
  padding: 4px;
}

badge {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<Table responsive bordered>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>AWS Certified Solutions Architect</th>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">EC2</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">Serverless</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">CI/CD</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">VPC</Badge>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Front-End</th>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">React</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">Jest/Enzyme</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">HTML</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">CSS</Badge>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Badge variant="info">Bootstrap</Badge>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Adding `display: block` to the badges should work.